# Outputting a base-proof expression

Tags: number, arithmetic, metagolf

### Background

In some possible futures, the world will convert their numerical systems from decimal (base 10 or `b10`) to some other base (binary `b2`, octal `b8`, hexadecimal `b16`, or even unary `b1`, in which case we're screwed!). Thus, in preparation for this possible world-changing event, you decide to base-proof all of your programs. This can be done by using only singular `0`s and `1`s in conjunction with operators to replace the existing number constants.

However, there's just one problem: You have a ton of programs to change, and manually converting each number to an expression would take weeks! Thus, you decide to write a program (or function) to decide for you what expression should replace each number.

### Input

The input will be a positive integer. Your code **must** be able to handle any integer up to 1000.

(If your code supports decimals and/or negative inputs, see **Scoring** below.)

### Output

Your code must output an expression that evaluates to the input in at least one language. This may be any language; it does not have to be the same one your program or function is written in. Also, this expression does not need to be a full program or function.

For clarity, the output may contain any of these operations:

- increment / decrement
- add / sum
- subtract / negate
- multiply / double (only if it doesn't directly involve the number `2`!)
- divide / modulo
- exponents / logarithms
- square / sqrt (again, only if these don't directly involve the number `2`!)
- bitwise operations (bOR, bAND, bNOT, bXOR, bit-shifts)
- setting / getting variables
- stack manipulation

You may **not** use `eval()` or any similar functions in the output. You may also not use in the output any functions that perform an action(s) other than the ones mentioned above.

Oh, and one more thing: since we want the output to be valid in as many bases as possible, the only number constants it may contain are `0` and `1`. Numbers such as `10` (ten) are disallowed, unless the language interprets it as a `1` and a `0`. Using strings to contain numbers is not allowed either, as is using characters such as CJam's `A`-`K` (which represent `10`-`20`).

### Test-cases

(All outputs are in JavaScript, but may work in other languages.)

**Input 1:**

```
2
```

**Possible output 1:**

```
1+1
```

**Input 2:**

```
13
```

**Possible output 2:**

```
(a=1+1+1)*a+a+1
```

**Input 3:**

```
60
```

**Possible output 3:**

```
(b=(a=1+1+1+1)*a)*a-a
```

**Input 4:**

```
777
```

**Possible output 4:**

```
(c=(b=((a=1+1+1+1)*a-a+1)*a)*a+b)+c+c-a+1
```

**Input 5:**

```
1000
```

**Possible output 5:**

```
Math.pow((a=1+1+1)*a+1,a)
```

---

### Scoring

The goal of this challenge is to shorten your code's output as much as possible. Your score will be calculated in this way:

- **Base score:** The average byte-count of all outputs for integers 1 to 1000.
- **Decimal score:** If your code supports at least 3 decimal places, this is the average byte-count of all outputs of the sequence of numbers starting at `0.001` and ending at `1000`, increasing by `1.001` each time. `0.001, 1.002, 2.003...998.999, 1000.000` Then take 50% off of this score.
- **Negative score:** If your code supports negative numbers and zero, this is the average byte-count of the outputs of all integers from `-1000` to `0`. Then take 10% off of this score.

(The easiest way to calculate these would likely be a loop with your program/function inside.)

**Your final score is the average of whichever of the above formulas apply.**

If the output is non-deterministic (i.e. somewhat random; multiple runs with the same input produces multiple unique outputs), then the score for each input is determined by the largest output over ten runs on my CPU.

Also, as you don't know how precious computer data will be in the future, **the byte-count of your generator code must be less than 512 bytes.**

<s>**Lowest score in two weeks (on Sep 30) will be declared the winner.**</s> Congratulations to your winner, **@ThomasKwa**!

---

### Leaderboard

```js
var QUESTION_ID=58084,OVERRIDE_USER=42545;function answersUrl(e){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[3],language:a[1]+'/'+a[2],lang2:a[2],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size.toFixed(3)).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.lang2,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){var E=e.lang.toLowerCase(),S=s.lang.toLowerCase();return E>S?1:E<S?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size.toFixed(3)).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,])\/([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?([\.\d]+)(?=[^\n\.\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\.\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Languages</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Output Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

To make sure your answer shows up correctly, please start it with this header:

```
# Language name/Other language name, X points
```

Where `X` is the score of your answer. Example:

```
# CJam/Pyth, 25.38 points
```

If you have any questions or suggestions, please let me know. Good luck!

Comment: Can I use variables that hold `0` or `1` by default?

Comment: @Dennis I don't see any problem with that, so go ahead!

Comment: I'm assuming I can't do base conversion between base 2 and the default base.

Comment: @muddyfish Nope, no base conversion allowed in the output.

Comment: I guess we also are not allowed to use something like `Integer.parseInt("1000", 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)`? I'm pretty sure `parseInt` uses only the allowed operations ;-)

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann No, that would go against this rule, or at least the main intention of it: "Numbers such as `10` (ten) are disallowed, unless the language interprets it as a `1` and a `0`." I'll edit to make this more clear.

Comment: Are the constants allowed to contain loops? For example Beam `'''>\`++++++++)` = 24

Comment: @MickyT Loops are OK, at least in that case, as Beam does not have built-in multiplication.

Comment: @ETHproductions Is the 512B limit for the generat*ing* or the generat*ed* code?

Comment: @minxomat For the generat*ing*.

Comment: @ETHproductions The negative score uses one step more than the base score `({-1000..0} > {1..1000})`. Intended?

Comment: @minxomat Yes, this is to score the `0` case. Although now that I think about it, it may be better to include `0` in the base score instead. (Also, I keep reading your username as min-mix-o-mat. ;) )

Comment: Are bit shift operations on `h` also illegal?

Comment: @ThomasKwa Bit-shifts are OK, as long as a) it's only a shift by 1 bit (also known as doubling/halving), or b) the number of bits it is shifted by is calculated the same way as regular numbers.

Comment: The z80's "shift left logical" instruction shifts a `1` into bit 0.

Comment: @ThomasKwa Thanks for the info. I believe that's still alright; it's not too much different from the default behavior.

Comment: Which of these single instructions are legal (provided they do not contain literals other than `0` and `1`: Pyth's `y` (double), a hypothetical left trit-shift by 1 on a ternary computer, a left bit shift by 2 implemented by adding a number to itself twice, square (implemented by multiplying a number by itself), cube, square root, cube root, "push a number of 1s given by the number on top of the stack", sum of all numbers from 1 to n, sum of all numbers on the stack, increment twice, add `hl` to the stack pointer?

Comment: @ThomasKwa Doubling is fine; you're already using that in your answer (`) add hl, hl`). I'm gonna say squares, square and cube roots, sum entire stack, and "push a number of 1s given by the number on top of the stack" are fine as well. I'm not sure what you mean by "add `hl` to the stack pointer"; it would be great if you could elaborate. None of the others are allowed, including "a hypothetical left trit-shift by 1 on a ternary computer", which is exactly the same as tripling.

Comment: The z80 has a stack pointer `sp`; when a register pair is pushed it decrements twice to point to the top of the stack, and when a register pair is popped it increments twice. I was thinking of using `push de` and `add hl,sp` to subtract 3 from hl.

Comment: @ThomasKwa Alright, I guess that's OK. IMHO, it's actually a pretty clever solution to subtract 3 in 2 bytes. May I ask what `push de` is referring to?

Comment: `push de` pushes the register pair `de` onto the stack.

Comment: @ThomasKwa Well yeah, I guess I figured that. I should learn more about z80 machine code. Also, congratulations on your win! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Python/Zilog Z80 machine code, <s>11.653</s> 11.488

```
import math,numpy as np
def R(n):
    if n==0:return []
    if n<0:return -R(-n)
    e=int(math.log(n,2))
    if n >= 5/3 * 2**e:
        return np.append(2**(e+1),-R(2**(e+1)-n))
    return np.append(2**e,R(n-2**e))

def strR(n):
    b = R(n)
    s = ""
    if n==0:return s
    e=max(abs(b))
    while e:
        if e in b:s+="#"
        elif -e in b:s+="+"
        s+=")"
        e//=2
    return s[:-1]
```

Bonuses: Negative numbers.

Assumes that the `hl` register pair initially holds 0, and returns the result in `hl`.

Only these three instructions are used:

```
ASCII   Hex    Instruction
--------------------------
#       23     inc hl
)       29     add hl,hl
+       2B     dec hl
```

We use a small modification of the [minimum-weight balanced binary representation BBR2](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~shallit/Papers/bbr.pdf). Since BBR2 minimizes the weight (number of nonzero digits), but we want to minimize the weight plus the number of bit shifts, we change a constant in the algorithm from `3/2` to `5/3`.

To compute the score and verify, use this code:

```
def verify(n):
v = 0
for c in strR(n):
    if c=="#":v += 1
    elif c=="+":v -= 1
    else: v *= 2
return v==n

print(0.5*(sum([len(strR(n)) for n in range(1,1001)])/1000 + \
           sum([len(strR(n)) for n in range(-1000,1)])/1001 * 0.9))

print(all([verify(n) for n in range(-1000,1001)]))
```

Example output:

```
strR(486)
         '#)))))+)+))+)'
```

Or in assembly:

```
inc hl \ add hl,hl \ add hl,hl \ add hl,hl \ add hl,hl \ add hl,hl \ dec hl \ add hl,hl \ dec hl \ add hl,hl \ add hl,hl \ dec hl \ add hl,hl
```

More example programs:

```
-256  +))))))))
-255  +))))))))#
-254  +)))))))#)
-253  +)))))))#)#
-252  +))))))#))
-251  +))))))#))#
-250  +))))))#)#)
-249  +)))))#)))+
-248  +)))))#)))
-247  +)))))#)))#
-246  +)))))#))#)
-245  +)))))#))#)#
-244  +)))))#)#))
-243  +)))))#)#))#
-242  +))))#)))+)
-241  +))))#))))+

  -5  +))+
  -4  +))
  -3  +)+
  -2  +)
  -1  +
   0  
   1  #
   2  #)
   3  #)#
   4  #))
   5  #))#
```

Possible optimizations: OP rules that the `inc h` and `dec h` instructions, which directly change the upper byte of `hl`, are illegal, but `sla h` and the undocumented `sl1 h` (left bit shifts by 1 on `h` that shift in a `0` and `1` respectively) are permitted. `sla h` and `sl1 h` are two bytes each, but they can sometimes shorten the output.

Comment: Very nice, the lowest so far! I guess this is one instance where pure machine code comes in handy. ;)

Comment: +1 this is probably unbeatable. Also for the genius of using machine code (on a cpu with a largely 8 bit instruction set and some 16 bit registers.)

Comment: It's weird how `+` translates to `dec`. I keep reading the negative examples wrong.

Answer (score 9):

## CJam/CJam, <s>143.263</s> <s>42.713</s> <s>28.899</s> <s>23.901</s> <s>21.903</s> 20.468

```
ri
[
    ['X\2b1>e`{~{"1)*)"*}{_({(')*1\"m<"}{"1)*"*}?}?}/]s
    "X1)*"/"1)"*
    "1)1)*"/"1)))"*
    "X1)m<"/"1)))"*
    _"1)"/("1):Y"+\'Y*+
]
{,}$0=
```

No bonuses apply.

Try it online: [sample run](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ri%0A%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%5B'X%5C2b1%3Ee%60%7B~%7B%221)*)%22*%7D%7B_(%7B(')*1%5C%22m%3C%22%7D%7B%221)*%22*%7D%3F%7D%3F%7D%2F%5Ds%0A%20%20%20%20%22X1)*%22%2F%221)%22*%0A%20%20%20%20%221)1)*%22%2F%221)))%22*%0A%20%20%20%20%22X1)m%3C%22%2F%221)))%22*%0A%20%20%20%20_%221)%22%2F(%221)%3AY%22%2B%5C'Y*%2B%0A%5D%0A%7B%2C%7D%240%3D&input=60) | [score calculator](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=1000%2C%3A)%5B%7B%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%5B'X%5C2b1%3Ee%60%7B~%7B%221)*)%22*%7D%7B_(%7B(')*1%5C%22m%3C%22%7D%7B%221)*%22*%7D%3F%7D%3F%7D%2F%5Ds%0A%20%20%20%20%22X1)*%22%2F%221)%22*%0A%20%20%20%20%221)1)*%22%2F%221)))%22*%0A%20%20%20%20%22X1)m%3C%22%2F%221)))%22*%0A%20%20%20%20_%221)%22%2F(%221)%3AY%22%2B%5C'Y*%2B%0A%5D%7B%2C%7D%240%3D%2C%7D%2F%5D%3A%2Be-3) | [verification](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=1000%2C%3A)_%5B%7B%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%5B'X%5C2b1%3Ee%60%7B~%7B%221)*)%22*%7D%7B_(%7B(')*1%5C%22m%3C%22%7D%7B%221)*%22*%7D%3F%7D%3F%7D%2F%5Ds%0A%20%20%20%20%22X1)*%22%2F%221)%22*%0A%20%20%20%20%221)1)*%22%2F%221)))%22*%0A%20%20%20%20%22X1)m%3C%22%2F%221)))%22*%0A%20%20%20%20_%221)%22%2F(%221)%3AY%22%2B%5C'Y*%2B%0A%5D%7B%2C%7D%240%3D~%7D%2F%5D%3D)

#### Example runs

```
   1 X
   2 1)
   3 1))
   4 1)))
   5 1))))
   6 1))1)*
   7 1))1)*)
   8 X1))m<
   9 1)))1)*)
  10 1))))1)*
  11 1))))1)*)
  12 1))1)m<
  13 1))1)*1)*)
  14 1))1)*)1)*
  15 1))1)*)1)*)
  16 X1)))m<
  17 X1))m<1)*)
  18 1)))1)*)1)*
  19 1)))1)*)1)*)
  20 1))))1)m<
```

```
 981 1):Y)Y*)Y*)Y*Y*)Y*Y*)Y*Y*)
 982 1):Y)Y*)Y*)Y*Y*)Y*Y*)Y*)Y*
 983 1):Y)Y*)Y*)Y*Y*)Y*Y*)Y*)Y*)
 984 1):Y)Y*)Y*)Y*Y*)Y*)Y)m<
 985 1):Y)Y*)Y*)Y*Y*)Y*)Ym<Y*)
 986 1):Y)Y*)Y*)Y*Y*)Y*)Y*Y*)Y*
 987 1):Y)Y*)Y*)Y*Y*)Y*)Y*Y*)Y*)
 988 1):Y)Y*)Y*)Y*Y*)Y*)Y*)Ym<
 989 1):Y)Y*)Y*)Y*Y*)Y*)Y*)Y*Y*)
 990 1):Y)Y*)Y*)Y*Y*)Y*)Y*)Y*)Y*
 991 1):Y)Y*)Y*)Y*Y*)Y*)Y*)Y*)Y*)
 992 1):Y)Y*)Y*)Y*)Y)))m<
 993 1):Y)Y*)Y*)Y*)Y))m<Y*)
 994 1):Y)Y*)Y*)Y*)Y)m<Y*)Y*
 995 1):Y)Y*)Y*)Y*)Y)m<Y*)Y*)
 996 1):Y)Y*)Y*)Y*)Ym<Y*)Ym<
 997 1):Y)Y*)Y*)Y*)Ym<Y*)Y*Y*)
 998 1):Y)Y*)Y*)Y*)Ym<Y*)Y*)Y*
 999 1):Y)Y*)Y*)Y*)Ym<Y*)Y*)Y*)
1000 1):Y)Y*)Y*)Y*)Y*Y*)Y)m<
```

Comment: My word, that was fast! The links don't work in Firefox, though.

Comment: Since this isn't code golf, I replaced each `%` with a longer expression. The links should work now.

Comment: Input 34 gives 1. On which input does it work better

Comment: @KishanKumar The *verification* tests all 1000 possible inputs. Output *1* indicates that the comparison was successful.

Comment: Could you add some example outputs?

Answer (score 3):

### Ceylon/Ceylon, <s>49.86</s> 40.95 points

The third version uses Ceylon 1.2 for the generator and 509 bytes of code:

`import ceylon.language{S=String,I=Integer,e=expand}S q(I n)=>n==0then"0"else(n<0then"-"+p(-n,"-")else p(n,"+"));variable Map<[I,S],S>c=map{};S p(I n,S s){S v=c[[n,s]]else(n<8then s.join([1].repeat(n)))else(let(a="+-".replace(s,""))e(e{for(x in 2..8)let(l=(n^(1.0/x)).integer){for(r in l:2)if(r>1)let(w=r^x){if(w-n<n)"("+p(r,"+")+")^("+p(x,"+")+")"+(w<n then s+p(n-w,s)else(n<w then a+p(w-n,a)else""))}}}).reduce<S>((x,y)=>x.size<y.size then x else y))else"";c=[n,s]in c then c else map{[n,s]->v,*c};return v;}`

It gets down to 35.22 points, but I won't put this in the title line because Celyon 1.2 only was published at october 29. I don't think I would be able to implement this algorithm in Ceylon 1.1 in this size.). More details down there, here I'll describe the second version. (The first version can be seen in the history – it supported only positive numbers, but did fit into 256 bytes.)

#### Second version

Now the second version, which supports negative integers (and 0), and generally creates a bit shorter output by using in addition `-`.
(This version actually uses the permitted length, the first one tried to stay under 256 bytes instead of 512.)

```
String proof(Integer n) {
    if (n == 0) { return "0"; }
    if (n < 0) { return "-" + p(-n, "-"); }
    return p(n, "+");
}
String p(Integer n, String sign) {
    if (n < 9) {
        return sign.join([1].repeat(n));
    }
    value anti = (sign == "+") then "-" else "+";
    value root = ((n^0.5) + 0.5).integer;
    return "(" + p(root, "+") + ")^(1+1)" +
       ( (root^2 < n) then sign + p(n - root^2, sign) else
         ((n < root^2) then anti + p(root^2 - n, anti) else ""));
}
```

Code has length 487, so there is still some space for more optimizations later. (There are also lots of reserves in form of whitespace and long variable names.)

The scoring:

```
Total positive: 42652
Average positive:42.652
Total negative: 43653
Average negative: 43.60939060939061
With bonus:39.24845154845155
Overall score: 40.95022577422577
```

Some sample outputs:

```
   27:  21: (1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)+1+1
   28:  23: (1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)+1+1+1
   29:  25: (1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)+1+1+1+1
   30:  27: (1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)+1+1+1+1+1
   31:  29: (1+1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)-1-1-1-1-1
   32:  27: (1+1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)-1-1-1-1
   33:  25: (1+1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)-1-1-1
   34:  23: (1+1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)-1-1

  -27:  22: -(1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)-1-1
  -28:  24: -(1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)-1-1-1
  -29:  26: -(1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)-1-1-1-1
  -30:  28: -(1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)-1-1-1-1-1
  -31:  30: -(1+1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)+1+1+1+1+1
  -32:  28: -(1+1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)+1+1+1+1
  -33:  26: -(1+1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)+1+1+1
  -34:  24: -(1+1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)+1+1


  993:  65: ((1+1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)-1-1-1-1)^(1+1)-(1+1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)+1+1+1+1+1
  994:  63: ((1+1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)-1-1-1-1)^(1+1)-(1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)-1-1-1-1-1
  995:  61: ((1+1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)-1-1-1-1)^(1+1)-(1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)-1-1-1-1
  996:  59: ((1+1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)-1-1-1-1)^(1+1)-(1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)-1-1-1
  997:  57: ((1+1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)-1-1-1-1)^(1+1)-(1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)-1-1
  998:  55: ((1+1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)-1-1-1-1)^(1+1)-(1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)-1
  999:  53: ((1+1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)-1-1-1-1)^(1+1)-(1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)
 1000:  55: ((1+1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)-1-1-1-1)^(1+1)-(1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)+1

 -993:  66: -((1+1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)-1-1-1-1)^(1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)-1-1-1-1-1
 -994:  64: -((1+1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)-1-1-1-1)^(1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)+1+1+1+1+1
 -995:  62: -((1+1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)-1-1-1-1)^(1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)+1+1+1+1
 -996:  60: -((1+1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)-1-1-1-1)^(1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)+1+1+1
 -997:  58: -((1+1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)-1-1-1-1)^(1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)+1+1
 -998:  56: -((1+1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)-1-1-1-1)^(1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)+1
 -999:  54: -((1+1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)-1-1-1-1)^(1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)
-1000:  56: -((1+1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)-1-1-1-1)^(1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1)^(1+1)-1

    1:   1: 1
    2:   3: 1+1
    3:   5: 1+1+1
    4:   7: 1+1+1+1
    5:   9: 1+1+1+1+1
    6:  11: 1+1+1+1+1+1
    7:  13: 1+1+1+1+1+1+1
    8:  15: 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1
    9:  13: (1+1+1)^(1+1)
   10:  15: (1+1+1)^(1+1)+1

    0:   1: 0
   -1:   2: -1
   -2:   4: -1-1
   -3:   6: -1-1-1
   -4:   8: -1-1-1-1
   -5:  10: -1-1-1-1-1
   -6:  12: -1-1-1-1-1-1
   -7:  14: -1-1-1-1-1-1-1
   -8:  16: -1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1
   -9:  14: -(1+1+1)^(1+1)
  -10:  16: -(1+1+1)^(1+1)-1
```

As you can see, the negative ones are always one byte (the leading `-`) longer than the corresponding positive ones.

The base idea is the same as the previous program: find a square near our target number, and represent its root and the remainder recursively.
But now we allow our square being also some larger than the target number, which then makes the remainder negative.
(The `+0.5` can be changed to a different constant to tweak the algorithm, but it seems that I already did hit the optimum here – both 0.4 and 0.6 give worse results.)

To make negative values negative (and otherwise have the same structure as the positive ones, we pass the operator `sign` to our recursive function `p` – that is either `"+"` or `"-"`. We can use that for the joiner in the trivial cases (i.e. n < 9) as well as for the remainder if it's positive, and use the opposite sign for the remainder if it is negative.

The `proof` function handles the initial sign (with a special case for 0), the `p` function does the actual work, with recursion.

#### Third version, for Ceylon 1.2

```
import ceylon.language { S=String, I=Integer,e=expand }

// output a base-proof Ceylon expression for an integer
// (i.e. using only 0 and 1 as digits).
//
// Question: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/58084/2338
// My Answer:  http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58122/2338
//
// The goal is to produce an expression as short as possible, with
// the code staying under 512 bytes in length.
//
// This approach is to represent a positive integer as a square
// of a positive integer plus some remainder (where the remainder
// can be negative), and for negative integers replace the + on the
// outer level by -.

S q(I n) =>
        n == 0 then "0"
        else (n < 0 then "-" + p(-n, "-")
            else p(n, "+"));

// cache for values of p
variable Map<[I, S],S> c = map { };

// Transforms a positive number into a base-proof term, using
// the given sign for the summation on the outer level.
S p(I n, S s) {
    S v =
    // look into the cache
            c[[n, s]] else (
        // hard-code small numbers
        n < 8 then s.join([1].repeat(n)))
            else
    // do the complicated stuff
    (let (a = "+-".replace(s,""))
            e(e {
                    for (x in 2..8) // try these exponents
                        let (l = (n ^ (1.0 / x)).integer) // \[ sqrt[exp]{n} \] in LaTeX
                            { for (r in l:2) // lowerRoot, lowerRoot + 1
                                    if (r > 1)
                                        let (w = r ^ x)
                                            { if (w-n < n) // avoid recursion to larger or same number
                                                    // format the string as  r^x + (n-w)
                                                    "(" + p(r, "+") + ")^(" + p(x, "+") + ")" +
                                                            (w < n then s + p(n - w, s)
                                                                else (n < w then a + p(w - n, a)
                                                                    else ""))
                                            } } })
            // and now find the shortest formatted string
                .reduce<S>((x, y) => x.size < y.size then x else y))
    // this should never happen, but we can't tell the compiler
    // that at least some of the iterables are non-empty due to the if clause.
            else "";

    // this builds a new cache in each step – quite wasteful,
    // as this also happens when the value was found in the cache,
    // but we don't have more characters remaining.
    //// c = map { [n, s] -> v, *c };
    ///better way:
     c = [n,s] in c then c else map{[n,s]->v, *c}; 
    return v;
}
```

The golfed version (i.e. comments and whitespace removed) is posted at the top, at exactly 509 bytes of code.

This uses the same base principle as the second version, but instead of just squares, it also tries to use higher powers of numbers (trying exponents from 2 to 8), and uses the shortest result. It also caches the results, as otherwise this would be unacceptably slow for larger numbers with many recursive calls.

Scoring:

```
Total positive: 36622
Average positive: 36.622
Total negative: 37623
Average negative: 37.58541458541458
With bonus:33.826873126873124
Overall score: 35.22443656343656
```

The big indented construct in the middle are three nested iterable comprehensions, the inner two inside a let expression. These are then unnested using the expand function twice, and the `reduce` function finds the shortest of those strings.

I've filed a [feature request](https://github.com/ceylon/ceylon-spec/issues/1458#issuecomment-152881872) to be able to do this in a single comprehension.

Inside the comprehension, we are building a string from the root `r`, the exponent `x` and the remainder (`n-w` or `w-n`).

The `let` expression and the `map` function are new in Ceylon 1.2. `map` could have been replaced by `HashMap` (which would have needed more characters for the import, although it would probably be even faster, as I wouldn't build the map new for each new entry). The `let` expressions like `let (w = r ^ x)` could have been replaced by using an `if` clause like `if(exists w = true then r ^ x)` (and then I wouldn't have needed the two `expand` calls either), but this would still be a bit longer, not fitting inside the 511 allowed bytes.

Here the sample outputs corresponding to those selected above, all of them except the really small numbers are shorter:

```
   27:  15: (1+1+1)^(1+1+1)
   28:  17: (1+1+1)^(1+1+1)+1
   29:  19: (1+1+1)^(1+1+1)+1+1
   30:  21: (1+1)^(1+1+1+1+1)-1-1
   31:  19: (1+1)^(1+1+1+1+1)-1
   32:  17: (1+1)^(1+1+1+1+1)
   33:  19: (1+1)^(1+1+1+1+1)+1
   34:  21: (1+1)^(1+1+1+1+1)+1+1

  -27:  16: -(1+1+1)^(1+1+1)
  -28:  18: -(1+1+1)^(1+1+1)-1
  -29:  20: -(1+1+1)^(1+1+1)-1-1
  -30:  22: -(1+1)^(1+1+1+1+1)+1+1
  -31:  20: -(1+1)^(1+1+1+1+1)+1
  -32:  18: -(1+1)^(1+1+1+1+1)
  -33:  20: -(1+1)^(1+1+1+1+1)-1
  -34:  22: -(1+1)^(1+1+1+1+1)-1-1

  993:  39: ((1+1+1)^(1+1)+1)^(1+1+1)-1-1-1-1-1-1-1
  994:  37: ((1+1+1)^(1+1)+1)^(1+1+1)-1-1-1-1-1-1
  995:  35: ((1+1+1)^(1+1)+1)^(1+1+1)-1-1-1-1-1
  996:  33: ((1+1+1)^(1+1)+1)^(1+1+1)-1-1-1-1
  997:  31: ((1+1+1)^(1+1)+1)^(1+1+1)-1-1-1
  998:  29: ((1+1+1)^(1+1)+1)^(1+1+1)-1-1
  999:  27: ((1+1+1)^(1+1)+1)^(1+1+1)-1
 1000:  25: ((1+1+1)^(1+1)+1)^(1+1+1)

 -993:  40: -((1+1+1)^(1+1)+1)^(1+1+1)+1+1+1+1+1+1+1
 -994:  38: -((1+1+1)^(1+1)+1)^(1+1+1)+1+1+1+1+1+1
 -995:  36: -((1+1+1)^(1+1)+1)^(1+1+1)+1+1+1+1+1
 -996:  34: -((1+1+1)^(1+1)+1)^(1+1+1)+1+1+1+1
 -997:  32: -((1+1+1)^(1+1)+1)^(1+1+1)+1+1+1
 -998:  30: -((1+1+1)^(1+1)+1)^(1+1+1)+1+1
 -999:  28: -((1+1+1)^(1+1)+1)^(1+1+1)+1
-1000:  26: -((1+1+1)^(1+1)+1)^(1+1+1)

    1:   1: 1
    2:   3: 1+1
    3:   5: 1+1+1
    4:   7: 1+1+1+1
    5:   9: 1+1+1+1+1
    6:  11: 1+1+1+1+1+1
    7:  13: 1+1+1+1+1+1+1
    8:  13: (1+1)^(1+1+1)
    9:  13: (1+1+1)^(1+1)
   10:  15: (1+1+1)^(1+1)+1

    0:   1: 0
   -1:   2: -1
   -2:   4: -1-1
   -3:   6: -1-1-1
   -4:   8: -1-1-1-1
   -5:  10: -1-1-1-1-1
   -6:  12: -1-1-1-1-1-1
   -7:  14: -1-1-1-1-1-1-1
   -8:  14: -(1+1)^(1+1+1)
   -9:  14: -(1+1+1)^(1+1)
  -10:  16: -(1+1+1)^(1+1)-1
```

For example, now we have 1000 = (3^2 + 1)^3, instead of 1000 = (6^2-4)^2-5^2+1.

Comment: I did wrongly remember the program restriction as 256 bytes ... in 512 quite a bit more can be done. Will try that later.

Comment: Nah, it says `less than 512`. Sou you can use a max. of 511 bytes ;)

Comment: *How have I never heard of this language?!?* :O But seriously, excellent explanation! I love to understand the techniques others use in their answers. +1

Comment: @ETHproductions I also only read of it about two weeks ago here on the site, and started to like it. So to get to know it better, I try to answer questions here using Ceylon.

Answer (score 3):

## [ß](https://github.com/minxomat/-S-)/BrainFuck, 34.201 points

#### [ß](https://github.com/minxomat/-S-) source (194B):

```
E='++[------>+<]>++'°\c[1]<0°{E&='.'µA=ß"-ß°°c[1]),'')µE&='+++'°/B=1°(A[0]°\A[B]='.'°{µE&='--.++'°]E&=ß~A'+',A[B])&'.'&ß~A'-',A[B])°}°)°'ß"&E,'+-')+ß"&E,'-+')>0µE=ß"'ß"'E,'-+',''),'+-','')°!€E)
```

If someone is interested, I'll add an explanation. The BF output is pretty optimized already, but I guess I could use the remaining 318B of ß code to implement

- a loop-nesting-optimization,
- more 8bit overflow shortcuts,
- <s>operator collision removal</s>.

#### Samples:

Running in windows:

```
$ sharps encode.ss 42
++[------>+<]>+++++++++.--.--

$ sharps encode.ss -42
++[------>+<]>++.+++++++.--.--

$ sharps encode.ss 1.427
++[------>+<]>++++++.---.++++++.--.+++++.-------

$ sharps encode.ss -946.427
++[------>+<]>++.++++++++++++.-----.++.--------.++++++.--.+++++.-------
```

Running in linux:

```
$ WINEDEBUG=-all wine sharps source.ss -4.72
++[------>+<]>++.+++++++.------.+++++++++.-----.--
```

Validate in the [online BF interpreter](http://brainfuck.tk).

#### Scores:

1. Base average `= 37.495`.
2. Decimal average `= 60.959 * 0.5 = ~30.48`.
3. Negative avg. `= 38.4765234765235 * 0.9 = ~34.629`
4. Avg of the above, final score `= (37.495 + 30.48 + 34.629)/3 = 34.201`.

Comment: I always like to see the new languages folks have created. :) Thanks for the score breakdown! I'd like to put more of a bonus on the decimal portion, so I've changed the deduction from 40% to 50%.

Comment: @ETHproductions Yeah, I'll try setting up an online interpreter for this. There are about 435 highly abstract operators, additional 9,9k can be defined ;-) . I've corrected the calculation (hopefully).

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby/Ruby, 29.77885

31.873*0.9 (negative) 30.872 (positive).

Basic strategy is symmetrical base 3 representation ("balanced ternary"), ie when the digits are `-1,0,1` instead of `0,1,2`

```
#function
f=->n{m=n  
  a='0' 
  7.times{|i|
    r=m%3;r-=r/2*3
    m=(m-r)/3
    #produce expression: replace 0 with (0*x+-1)
    #only add 0*x if there are higher base 3 digits to follow.
    #only add (..+-1) if the current base 3 digit is nonzero. 
    a.sub!('0',['','(','('][r]+(m.abs>0?'0*x':'')+['','+1)','-1)'][r])
  }
  #tidy up expression
  a.sub!('(-1)*','-')          #remove internal (-1)*
  a.sub!('(+1)*','')           #remove internal (+1)*
  a[-1]==')' && a=a[1..-2]     #remove unnecessary global brackets
  a.sub!('x','(x=1+1+1)')      #find the first x and define it as 1+1+1=3
  #special cases for small numbers 
  n.abs<8 && a=n==0?'0':['','1'+'+1'*(n-1).abs,'-1'*n.abs][n<=>0] 
  a 
}

#call like this
(1..1000).each{|p|
b=f.call(p)
puts b
```

Here's the output from 0 to 40 before cleanup

```
(+1)
((+1)*x-1)
(+1)*x
((+1)*x+1)
(((+1)*x-1)*x-1)
((+1)*x-1)*x
(((+1)*x-1)*x+1)
((+1)*x*x-1)
(+1)*x*x
((+1)*x*x+1)
(((+1)*x+1)*x-1)
((+1)*x+1)*x
(((+1)*x+1)*x+1)
((((+1)*x-1)*x-1)*x-1)
(((+1)*x-1)*x-1)*x
((((+1)*x-1)*x-1)*x+1)
(((+1)*x-1)*x*x-1)
((+1)*x-1)*x*x
(((+1)*x-1)*x*x+1)
((((+1)*x-1)*x+1)*x-1)
(((+1)*x-1)*x+1)*x
((((+1)*x-1)*x+1)*x+1)
(((+1)*x*x-1)*x-1)
((+1)*x*x-1)*x
(((+1)*x*x-1)*x+1)
((+1)*x*x*x-1)
(+1)*x*x*x
((+1)*x*x*x+1)
(((+1)*x*x+1)*x-1)
((+1)*x*x+1)*x
(((+1)*x*x+1)*x+1)
((((+1)*x+1)*x-1)*x-1)
(((+1)*x+1)*x-1)*x
((((+1)*x+1)*x-1)*x+1)
(((+1)*x+1)*x*x-1)
((+1)*x+1)*x*x
(((+1)*x+1)*x*x+1)
((((+1)*x+1)*x+1)*x-1)
(((+1)*x+1)*x+1)*x
((((+1)*x+1)*x+1)*x+1)
```

And after cleanup

```
0
1
1+1
1+1+1
1+1+1+1
1+1+1+1+1
1+1+1+1+1+1
1+1+1+1+1+1+1
(x=1+1+1)*x-1
(x=1+1+1)*x
(x=1+1+1)*x+1
((x=1+1+1)+1)*x-1
((x=1+1+1)+1)*x
((x=1+1+1)+1)*x+1
(((x=1+1+1)-1)*x-1)*x-1
(((x=1+1+1)-1)*x-1)*x
(((x=1+1+1)-1)*x-1)*x+1
((x=1+1+1)-1)*x*x-1
((x=1+1+1)-1)*x*x
((x=1+1+1)-1)*x*x+1
(((x=1+1+1)-1)*x+1)*x-1
(((x=1+1+1)-1)*x+1)*x
(((x=1+1+1)-1)*x+1)*x+1
((x=1+1+1)*x-1)*x-1
((x=1+1+1)*x-1)*x
((x=1+1+1)*x-1)*x+1
(x=1+1+1)*x*x-1
(x=1+1+1)*x*x
(x=1+1+1)*x*x+1
((x=1+1+1)*x+1)*x-1
((x=1+1+1)*x+1)*x
((x=1+1+1)*x+1)*x+1
(((x=1+1+1)+1)*x-1)*x-1
(((x=1+1+1)+1)*x-1)*x
(((x=1+1+1)+1)*x-1)*x+1
((x=1+1+1)+1)*x*x-1
((x=1+1+1)+1)*x*x
((x=1+1+1)+1)*x*x+1
(((x=1+1+1)+1)*x+1)*x-1
(((x=1+1+1)+1)*x+1)*x
(((x=1+1+1)+1)*x+1)*x+1
```

Comment: I believe it's called "balanced ternary".

Comment: @ThomasKwa edited in, thanks

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby/dc, <del>20.296</del> <del>18.414</del> 16.968

Dynamic programming! Defines a list of functions that, given a dc instruction, return a new expression and the numeric value of that expression. Then, starting with `1` prefined, it builds a list of all reachable values up to and including the wanted value.

#### edit:

Added a function for *n-1* and made it run the algorithm through multiple passes. It seems to need 7 passes to stabilize. Had to shorten some variable names to stay within 512 bytes.

#### edit 2:

Added functions for *n(n-1)*, *n(n+1)* and *n^3* while I was at it. Shortened the code some more, landing at exactly 512 bytes.

```ruby
N = gets.to_i

fns = [
  ->(n,s){[n-1,   s+'1-']},
  ->(n,s){[n+1,   s+'1+']},
  ->(n,s){[n*2,   s+'d+']},
  ->(n,s){[n*3,   s+'dd++']},
  ->(n,s){[n*~-n, s+'d1-*']},
  ->(n,s){[n*n,   s+'d*']},
  ->(n,s){[n*-~n, s+'d1+*']},
  ->(n,s){[n*n*n, s+'dd**']},
]

lst = []*(N+1)
lst[0..2] = %w[0 1 1d+]

loop do
  prev = lst.dup

  (1..N).each do |n|
    fns.each do |f|
      m,s = f[n, lst[n]]
      lst[m] = s if m <= N && (lst[m].nil? || lst[m].size > s.size)
    end
  end

  break if lst == prev
end

puts lst[N]
```

#### Generated numbers:

Output consists entirely of five different characters: `1` pushes the value 1 on the stack; `d` duplicates the top of the stack; `+`, `-`, and `*`  pops the two top values and pushes their sum, difference, and product, respectively. Each generated expression adds only one value to the stack after execution.

```
   1: 1
   2: 1d+
   3: 1dd++
   4: 1d+d+
   5: 1d+d+1+
   6: 1d+dd++
   7: 1d+dd++1+
   8: 1d+dd**
   9: 1dd++d*
  10: 1d+d+1+d+
  11: 1d+d+1+d+1+
  12: 1dd++d1+*
  13: 1dd++d1+*1+
  14: 1d+dd++1+d+
  15: 1d+d+d*1-
  16: 1d+d+d*
  17: 1d+d+d*1+
  18: 1dd++d*d+
  19: 1dd++d*d+1+
  20: 1d+d+d1+*
  21: 1d+d+d1+*1+
  22: 1d+d+1+d+1+d+
  23: 1d+dd**dd++1-
  24: 1d+dd**dd++
  25: 1d+d+1+d*
```

...

```
 989: 1d+d+d*d+d1-*1-1-1-
 990: 1d+d+d*d+d1-*1-1-
 991: 1d+d+d*d+d1-*1-
 992: 1d+d+d*d+d1-*
 993: 1d+d+d*d+d1-*1+
 994: 1d+d+d*d+d1-*1+1+
 995: 1d+d+d*d+d1-*1+1+1+
 996: 1d+d+1+dd**d+1-d+d+
 997: 1d+d+1+d+dd**1-1-1-
 998: 1d+d+1+d+dd**1-1-
 999: 1d+d+1+d+dd**1-
1000: 1d+d+1+d+dd**
```

Comment: Pretty good, beating everything but z80 machine code so far (even Dennis' CJam!). Do you think you might be able to add in a `-` operator while staying within the byte count?

Comment: @ETHproductions How's that? ;) It shouldn't be hard to add negative numbers now, either.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2.6, <s>78.069</s> - 66.265 points

Submitting my answer for what it's worth (not a lot in this case ... but clearly demonstrating that for this challenge it's not enough to simply think of composing the output as a sum of bit-shifted values; when taken into account that no digits outside of 0 or 1 may  appear in the output). I might come back later with a different way of generating output.

The code itself is not too long (176 characters):

```
def f(a):return'+'.join(('(1<<%s)'%['0','+'.join('1'*x)][x>0]).replace('(1<<0)','1')for x in[i for i,e in enumerate(bin(a)[::-1][:-2])if int(e)])
print"".join(f(int(input())))
```

It generates correct but verbose output:

```
17
1+(1<<1+1+1+1)

800
(1<<1+1+1+1+1)+(1<<1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+(1<<1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)
```

Snippet that calculates the score:

```
def f(a):return'+'.join(('(1<<%s)'%['0','+'.join('1'*x)][x>0]).replace('(1<<0)','1')for x in[i for i,e in enumerate(bin(a)[::-1][:-2])if int(e)])
print sum(len("".join(f(i)))for i in range(1000))
```